# How can I prove that this sum is zero?

Tags: derivatives, summation, exterior-algebra

In the following let $J$ denote an ordered $k$-tuple $\{j_1, \ldots, j_k\}$, $1\leq j_1 <\cdots < j_k \leq n$, and $s$, $1\leq s\leq n$ such that $s\neq j_1,\ldots, j_k $. If $\phi_1,\ldots, \phi_k$ are $k$ smooth functions of $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ and $\dfrac{\partial(\phi_1, \ldots, \phi_k)}{\partial(x_{j_1}, \ldots, x_{j_k})}$ denote the determinant of the Jacobian of the map $\phi =(\phi_1, \ldots, \phi_k)$, then
$$\sum_{s,J} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_s}\dfrac{\partial(\phi_1, \ldots, \phi_k)}{\partial(x_{j_1}, \ldots, x_{j_k})} dx_s \wedge dx_{j_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{j_k} =0.$$
My idea is to form up complementary pairs so that we can have an internal cancellation. But how do we get the corresponding pairs of indices who will cancel each other. Please help me.

To make sure we can form up pairs we have to have the total number of terms in the sum should be even. I have worked out the total number of terms in the sum is $n_{C_k} \times (n-k) \times k$, and I believe that this is even.

If anyone have a better idea how to prove this sum is zero I will be grateful. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: I find myself rather busy right now so it would be difficult to furnish a detailed proof with all the calculations included, but you are right in what you suspect to be the case. By first grouping together the indices $(k, K)$ for which the subset $K \cup \{k\}$ is constant, you obtain a first reduction of your relation to a somewhat simpler sum. This simplified version can be expanded into a sum over the index set $[1, n+1] \times [1, n] \times \Sigma_n$, where $[r, s]$ is the natural interval between $r$ and $s$ and $\Sigma_m$ is the symmetric group of degree $m$ *(to be cont.)*

Comment: Having obtained this form of the relation, involving a summation over a triple-index family, a phenomenon of pair-wise cancelling does indeed occur: if $u_{h, k, \sigma}$ denotes the generic term in this summation and $h>k$, it will be the case that $u_{h, k, \sigma}=-u_{k, h-1, \sigma (k; h-1)}$, where for $1 \leqslant r \leqslant s \leqslant n$ I have taken the liberty to denote the cycle from $r$ increasingly onward to $s$ and then back to $r$ by $(r; s)$.